# G2/Froyo - Settings Quick Keys - How to set to "Wireless & Networks"

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire-z, quick-settings

When I configure my G2's "Quick Keys", I cannot set it to anything in "Settings > Wireless & Networks", except the main "WiFi settings" panel.

Ideally I would want quick keys assigned to "Tethering & portable hotspot", that would allow me to turn on data-forwarding quickly.

For the time being, I also need easy access to "Mobile network Settings", because I need to turn "Use only 2G networks" on and off, because I happen to be one of the lucky people that hit the data throttle, and cannot make voice calls when it is busy during the day.

Comment: Instead of using Quick Keys, you may be able to get widgets that will allow you to change these settings just as easily.

Comment: Can you make a suggestion? Day two of having to set my 2G-only flag is painful. Use data. Switch. Use voice. Switch. Is this what life is like on the Verizon network?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I have found to do this is using an app called [Any Cut](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appdroid.anycut).

Any Cut allows you to launch just about anything, follow these steps for the two that you mentioned (Tethering settings and Mobile Networks)

1. Install [Any Cut](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appdroid.anycut)
2. Pick a Quick Key to set (tap the key if unset currently or Home->Menu->Settings->Quick keys->[select a key])
3. Under **More**, tap **Any Cut**
4. Tap **Activity**
5. Select the activity you want to launch (**Network Settings** for Mobile Networks and the 2G/3G switch or **Settings** --the 7th **Settings** -- for Tethering & portable hotspot)

*Thanks to [Jeff Hamilton] for developing Any Cut (and releasing it for free) and also to [pikipirs] of XDA-Developers for [pointing out](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=690616&page=2) which settings option to use for tethering*